# Missing needed parameter access_token or code social Auth Google+ validation

Tags: django, django-authentication, python-social-auth, django-1.8, google-plus-signin

I'm working with Django1.8. Previously had a custom integration with Google+, would like to move to `python-social-auth` to make things easier.

Have followed the tutorial [here](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/backends/google.html?highlight=google#google-sign-in) on setting up **Google+** Sign in process. My request goes through (it logs me in to my Google+ account) but `python-social-auth` returns an error:

```
AuthMissingParameter at /auth/complete/google-plus/
Missing needed parameter access_token or code
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://localhost:8000/auth/complete/google-plus/
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: AuthMissingParameter
Exception Value:    
Missing needed parameter access_token or code
Exception Location: /Users/default/dev/mm-dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/google.py in auth_complete, line 140
Python Executable:  /Users/default/dev/mm-dev/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.10
Python Path:    
['/Users/default/dev/mm-dev',
 '/Users/default/dev/mm-dev/venv/src/contextio-v2.0-client-library',
 '/Users/default/dev/mm-dev/venv/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/default/dev/mm-dev/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/default/dev/mm-dev/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/default/dev/mm-dev/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/default/dev/mm-dev/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/default/dev/mm-dev/venv/Extras/lib/python',
 '/Users/default/dev/mm-dev/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/default/dev/mm-dev/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/default/dev/mm-dev/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages'
```

I'm a bit at a loss as to how to debug this issue. Isn't Google not returning the code back to me? I would expect an error to tell me what I'm missing with my configuration or request. How can I find out what the issue is with my request?

Comment: Have you tried running it with some tool like pdb or runserver_plus? I suspect the content of [self.data](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/backends/google.py#L138) you tell you more.
With Werkzeug, included in [runserver_plus](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/runserver_plus.html) you can run python (`print self.data` in your case) at any stage of your exception stack.